# Bibliography change the page numbering style

Tags: bibliographies, page-numbering

I am using the `book` class, so the page numbering is in the corners of the document.
When calling the `\bibliography` command, LaTeX creates a page with the standard numbering (centered, at the bottom) and then switches back to the book numbering for the rest of the bibliography pages.

What is happening here, how do I fix this?

Comment: The behavior you describe is standard for *all* numbered and unnumbered chapter-level headers (which includes the `Bibliography` sectioning header) of the `book` document class: the *first* page is set with the page style `plain` (with the page number placed centered at the bottom of the page), and additional pages are set with page style `headings`. If you don't like this setting and want to change it for the bibliography, you should probably change it for all chapter-level sectioning headers, whether numbered or unnumbered, as well.

Comment: OK I didn't realize this because I had removed the numbering on new chapter pages. Could you direct me to an explanation on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package with the `pagestyles` option lets you define different styles and assign them to 'normal' pages with `\pagestyle{<style>}` or just for the chapter pages with `\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{<style>}`.

Since you are using the book class, you can define the header and the footer for even and odd sides independently. For example:

```
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

\newpagestyle{main}{
 \headrule \footrule
 \sethead[][][\chaptertitle] %even
         {\sectiontitle}{}{} %odd
 \setfoot[\thepage][][] %even
         {}{}{\thepage} %odd
}

\newpagestyle{chap}{
 \footrule
 \setfoot[\thepage][][]
         {}{}{\thepage}
}
```

And then:

```
\pagestyle{main}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{chap}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your setup correctly, you want the first page of *every* chapter-level unit, whether numbered or unnumbered, to have no page number at all -- neither at the bottom center of a page nor in the header line.

You haven't indicated *how* you've achieved this look for the other chapter-level units, but one way of achieving this look *globally*, i.e., for the entire document, would be to insert the instructions

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\pagestyle{plain}
\makeatletter
```

in the preamble. These instructions "let" the `plain` page style (which prints a page number centered at the bottom of the page) to the `empty` page style. I think you can guess what the main characteristic of the `empty` page style is...

Comment: The "no page number on chapter pages" thing is something I set up (using `\thispagestyle{empty}`, by the way) because I found the change of style not very good looking, and disturbing for the reader. Your solution would perfectly do.

But I'd also be interested in a way to have the "corner numbering" everywhere, including chapter pages, which seems doable with your approach.